# Xcode 7 on Yosemite: XCTest no longer compiles in .mm objective-c++ files

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-yosemite, xcode7, objective-c++

After updating to Xcode 7 on OSX Yosemite (10.10.5) my `.mm` XCTest file now fails to compile. I get the following errors:

```
In file included from /Users/.../unit_test.mm:9:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/Headers/XCTest.h:32:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/SecItem.h:985:49: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
extern const CFStringRef kSecUseAuthenticationUI
                                                ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/SecItem.h:987:54: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
extern const CFStringRef kSecUseAuthenticationContext
                                                     ^
...
```

The lines it's complaining about all look like this:

```
extern const CFStringRef kSecUseAuthenticationUI
    __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_11, __IPHONE_9_0);
extern const CFStringRef kSecUseAuthenticationContext
    __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_11, __IPHONE_9_0);
```

Whereas it has no trouble with these declarations:

```
extern const CFStringRef kSecUseItemList
    __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_6, __IPHONE_2_0);
```

It looks like the update added the `__MAC_10_11` lines and `.mm` files no longer compile with XCTest on OS 10.10.

Does anyone know of a workaround besides upgrading to OS 10.11?

Thanks.

Comment: I have this same issue. It seems to want to compile using 10.11 SDK even on Yosemite and even when the deployment target is < 10.11. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: No. I'd love to hear one! :( I just removed the tests from my project. :/ I wasn't using them for much and haven't been changing that code. But its not great.

Comment: @blueether: you should upvote question if you have the same problem to increase visibility!

Comment: Ah darn, I'm getting errors generated out of Foundation so I can't simply remove stuff

Comment: Not the answer you're probably looking for, but my solution ended up being to just download Xcode 6.4 and installing it elsewhere. Not the best solution, but good enough for my needs. Hope that helps!

Comment: We're having the same problem [building OpenSceneGraph under Homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/46776#issuecomment-168449214). Hope someone figures out a broader solution.

Comment: I don't know if this answers your question, but in Objective-C++ try to use modules and see if that helps. I ran into weird compilation issues with Objective-C++ that went away when I replaced

    #import <Framework/Framework.h>

with

    @import Framework;

You will need to enable modules, Xcode will throw a compilation error that will include the compiler flag you need to enable it

Comment: Did you try using another SDK? You can have multiple macOS SDKs and switch between them.

You can download the SDK from here: https://github.com/phracker/MacOSX-SDKs/releases , this way you can use a newer SDK without upgrading macOS. You will need to edit one plist file. The link has the instructions to follow.